# Reference for sets of locally finite perimeter on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I am looking for a *reasonably complete* reference for Ennio De Giorgi's theory of sets of locally finite perimeter (also christened by him as *Caccioppoli sets*, after Renato Caccioppoli's pioneering work on the subject) and the associated theory of functions of locally bounded variation *in Riemannian manifolds*.

I am aware there are quite a few excellent references on the subject in Euclidean space, such as:

- L. Ambrosio, N. Fusco, D. Pallara, *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* (Oxford University Press, 2000);
- L. C. Evans, R. F. Gariepy, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* (CRC Press, 1992);
- H. Federer's classic, *Geometric Measure Theory* (Springer-Verlag, 1969 - particularly Section 4.5);
- M. Giaquinta, G. Modica, J. Soucek, *Cartesian Currents in the Calculus of Variations I* (Springer-Verlag, 1998);
- E. Giusti, *Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variation* (Birkhäuser, 1984);
- F. Maggi, *Sets of Finite Perimeter and Geometric Variational Problems* (Cambridge University Press, 2012);
- W. F. Pfeffer, *The Divergence Theorem and Sets of Finite Perimeter* (CRC Press, 2012);
- L. Simon, *Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory* (Australian National University, 1984);
- W. P. Ziemer, *Weakly Differentiable Functions* (Springer-Verlag, 1989).

However, the extension of this theory to Riemannian manifolds lies at the very basis of important topics in the latter such as isoperimetric inequalities, positive mass theorems and Penrose inequalities, which are also of importance in General Relativity. Most contemporary papers in the subject quote one or more of the above references and (implicitly or explicity) dismiss the work needed in performing such an extension as straightforward and thus left to the reader. A few papers do spell a few details of what should change in general Riemannian manifolds, but essentially restricting themselves to the very basics - i.e. the definition of functions of (locally) bounded variation and sets of (locally) finite perimeter therein, but no more. This makes these papers quite hermetic to newcomers.

At the other extreme, we do have an extension of De Giorgi's theory to *metric measure spaces* (which of course encompass Riemannian manifolds), but usually the treatments of such a far-reaching extension focus on aspects absent even on Riemannian manfolds. There is considerable interest in the particular case of *sub-Riemannian* manifolds, but these are also sufficiently far removed from Riemannian manifolds so as to be of little applicability to the latter.

I am particularly interested in the treatment of topics such as Part Two (Chapters 12-20) of F. Maggi's book cited above in the context of Riemannian manifolds. The closest thing I could find to what I am looking for is the [Diplomarbeit of Alexander Volkmann (2010)](https://alexandervolkmann.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/diplom.pdf) (see particularly Chapter 2), but it stops short of going beyond lower semicontinuity of perimeter and the ensuing closure of the class of sets of (locally) finite perimeter under finite unions and intersections. De Giorgi's structure theorem and Federer's theorem on the measure-theoretic boundary of sets of locally finite perimeter, for instance, seem to find no discussion at all in the literature of Riemannian manifolds, despite their obvious importance. Other references that do discuss a few aspects of the theory in the context of Riemannian manifolds are

- M. Miranda, D. Pallara, F. Paroneto and M. Preunkert, *Heat semigroup and functions of bounded
  variation on Riemannian manifolds*, J. reine angew. Math. **613** (2007) 99-119;
- A. Carbonaro, G. Mauceri, *A note on bounded variation and heat semigroup on Riemannian manifolds*, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **76** (2007) 155-160;
- B. Güneysu, D. Pallara, *Functions with bounded variation on a class of Riemannian manifolds with Ricci curvature unbounded from below*, Math. Ann. **363** (2015) 1307-1331,

but all of the above are rather focused on the extension of De Giorgi's heat kernel characterization of the variation of $L^1$ functions to Riemannian manifolds and do not go much further than that.

Comment: I wish there was more work in this area. Thanks for sharing what you have - the Volkmann reference saved me a lot of work. (The link above doesn't work for me, but I found it at https://alexandervolkmann.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/diplom.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the broken link (though gmvh has already edited my post with the active link). It has been a while...

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Apologies for commenting on an old question; in case you are still interested, I wanted to write a quick comment. At first sight Leon Simon's book seems to be set in Euclidean space, but the statements actually apply to subsets of Riemannian manifolds. For the general theory - including Allard regularity for example -, you can either work in charts or with a Nash embedding. In fact, for some chapters (including the 37th, 'Codimension 1 Minimizing Currents'), Leon Simon's book explicitly works with subsets of Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: @LeoMoos thanks for the comment. I have no doubt that the main results of De Giorgi's theory should still hold for Riemannian manifolds, but the actual proofs in the correct generality cannot be easily found in a systematic form in a reference that can be cited - they rather remain either as scattered, incomplete pieces or as folklore. Moreover, you seem to refer to results on Federer's theory of rectifiable sets and currents (which is admittedly more general) rather than De Giorgi's approach. Simon's book is no different - the discussion in Section 14 is restricted to Euclidean space.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro It's difficult to make an absolute statement ('the proofs in Simon's book all apply in Riemannian manifolds'), but I think the truth is not far off. Since you mention Section 14, the results given there - notably Thm. 14.3 - do generalise immediately, because you can work in bilipschitz charts. The image of a set with finite perimeter in $(M,g)$ has finite perimeter with the Euclidean metric in the chart. Last, what you say about currents is not completely accurate. In the top dimension, currents (with boundaries representable by integration) are Caccioppoli sets.

Comment: @LeoMoos ok, let me elaborate on why I don't think Simon's book qualifies as a reference in the terms posed in my question. I do understand these results all generalize to Riemannian manifolds, but the point is that there is nontrivial (albeit straightforward) work to be done to get there and most of it isn't done in any reference I know of. As I said in the OP, "details are left to the reader" doesn't qualify - what you said of Simon's book can be said of most of the references I quoted in Euclidean space.

Comment: (continued) Volkmann's diploma thesis linked above illustrates what a reference I'm asking for should look like. Unfortunately, as I said above, it discusses only the very basics of De Giorgi's theory in the setting of Riemannian manifolds and key results are missing. Finally, regarding rectifiable sets and currents, by "more general" I meant they go beyond top dimension - due to that, the language used by Federer to discuss them is somewhat different from De Giorgi's. The latter's structure theorem forms precisely the bridge between both setups in top dimension.